# emacs breaks down text snippet copied from another X Window application

Tags: buffers, gnus, copy-paste

When I select with a mouse a block of text in Firefox or VIM for example, copy it and then try to paste in Emacs, it gets pasted, but unaligned, meaning that beginning of the lines shift away to the right.

What is happening, and what would be the appropriate solution? Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like you are trying to involve the terminal into this pasting procedure, i.e. you are not pressing `C-y`, but, probably do something like: invoke context menu, then select "paste" on Emacs running in terminal, is that so?

Comment: @wvxvw, thanks for comment. Yes, this is exactly what I'm trying to do, and in fact when I mouse-copy from VIM terminal (for example some piece of `C` pr `python`code), and try to paste in EMACS terminal, the layout and indentation is broken. I guess it may have something to do with TAB/spaces and indentation specific to the language?

Comment: I would just use `C-y`, I'm not sure what the reason for this behavior is.